# Как перенести одну переменую из одного .py на другой?

Tags: python, list, переменные

Вот один пример.

Первый файл `cr.py`

```
import random

def generateworld():
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaa = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaaa = random.randint(1, 150)
    aaab = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaac = random.randint(1, 150)
    aaad = random.randint(1, 100)

    worldinf = [a, aaa, aaaa, aaab, aaad, aaac, aaad]

    print(worldinf)
```

Второй файл `main.py`

Мне нужно чтобы переменную со списком `woerldinf` можно было вывести или изменить из первого файла во второй.

Что нужно делать для этого?

Comment: @insolor можно перевести пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращайте это значение через return, а в другом модуле импортируйте функцию, и вызывайте ее:

```
# cr.py
import random


def generateworld():
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaa = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaaa = random.randint(1, 150)
    aaab = random.randint(1, 100)
    aaac = random.randint(1, 150)
    aaad = random.randint(1, 100)

    return [a, aaa, aaaa, aaab, aaad, aaac, aaad]
```

```
# main.py
from cr import generateworld

worldinf = generageworld()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь сделать импорт.

main.py

```
from cr import generateworld
```

Comment: Только импорта не достаточно, чтобы получить значение worldinf